# Jmeter not navigating to next controller

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am doing a performance testing in Jmeter I have added the controller and request, but my problem is when I run the script the requests are not automatically/manually navigating to the next controller

Scripts [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QpIT.png)

Script results [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBtID.png)

I my case the scripts ***jmeter_login_and_view_dashboard*** running without any issues but is not navigation to next controller ***login checker*** or ***actions per login***

I don't know what I am missing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

We don't know as well because your screenshots don't tell the full story.

I can think of the following reasons:

1. You have [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler somewhere which stops the test
2. An error occurs you have [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configured to stop the test in case of error
3. There is an [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) and the condition is not met
4. The controller is using a [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and the CSV file is not present

So take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), normally it should provide at least a clue regarding what went wrong.